# SQL Queries take up longer than 1 hour

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

Some of our SQL-Queries take longer than 3hours to execute, which is really long considering that our database is currently around 5000 entries big.

Here the two longest statements:

```
/* Alte Jobs anzeigen */

update vwr_synch.listings set vwr_synch.listings.Alt="alt"
where vwr_synch.listings.JobKey not in (select vwr_synch.jobs.JobKey from vwr_synch.jobs)
;

update vwr_synch.listings set vwr_synch.listings.Alt="alt" where vwr_synch.listings.VWRStatus="NoJobs" or vwr_synch.listings.VWRStatus="Problem"
;


update vwr_synch.listings set vwr_synch.listings.Alt=NULL 
where vwr_synch.listings.VWRStatus="Active" and vwr_synch.listings.VWRRetry!="0" and vwr_synch.listings.Alt="alt"
;


/* Neue Jobs anzeigen */

update vwr_synch.jobs set vwr_synch.jobs.NeuAlt="Neu"
where vwr_synch.jobs.JobKey not in (select vwr_synch.listings.JobKey from vwr_synch.listings) and (vwr_synch.jobs.`Status`="Active" and vwr_synch.jobs.Retry="0")
;
```

Comment: are those views you are updating? It that what the vwr prefix is for?

Comment: @Donal No the vwr prefix is created by the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample code has multiple statements, so I'll just focus on the first one.

I prefer `not in` because of the semantics using `NULL`, although there is evidence that `not in` might be more efficient (see link in comments).  This is the first query:

```
update vwr_synch.listings
    set vwr_synch.listings.Alt = 'alt'
    where vwr_synch.listings.JobKey not in (select vwr_synch.jobs.JobKey from vwr_synch.jobs);
```

I would change it to:

```
update vwr_synch.listings l
    set l.Alt = 'alt'
    where not exists (select 1 from vwr_synch.jobs.JobKey jk where jk.JobKey = l.JobKey);
```

Then, for this to work efficiently, you need an index on `vwr_synch.jobs.JobKey(JobKey)`.

The next two statements are:

```
update vwr_synch.listings l
    set l.Alt = 'alt'
     where l.VWRStatus in ('NoJobs', 'Problem');

update vwr_synch.listings l
    set l.Alt = NULL 
    where l.VWRStatus = 'Active' and l.VWRRetry <> '0' and l.Alt = 'alt';
```

For these, you want an index on `vwr_synch.listings(VWRStatus, Alt, VWRRetry)`.

Comment: According to [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), `NOT EXISTS` is actually slower than `NOT IN`.. I would make the index the main thrust of your answer.

Comment: Also, use the where clauses to determine what indexes you need.  looking at your sql I see indexes needed on these columns: vwr_synch.listings.JobKey, vwr_synch.jobs.JobKey, vwr_synch.listings.VWRStatus, vwr_synch.listings.VWRRetry, vwr_synch.listings.Alt, vwr_synch.jobs.Status, vwr_synch.jobs.Retry

Comment: @Arth . . . I actually prefer `NOT IN` because the semantics are more what one expects.  `NOT IN` never returns true when one of the elements in the subquery is false.  I modified the answer, but I'm concerned by this comment in the blog:  "It's hard to tell exact reason for this . . .".